# How can I find the first element of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var a = {
 "message":"The request is invalid.",
 "modelState":{
    "model.ConfirmPassword":["The password and confirmation password do not match."]
  }
}

var keys = a.modelState.keys;
var firstError = a.modelState[keys[0]];
```

I would like to have the variable firstError set to "The password and confirmation password do not match."

However it is giving me "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "first" key as keys in objects [aren't ordered](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4).

If you want *any one*, you can do this :

```
var anyError = a.modelState[Object.keys(a.modelState)[0]];
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Atually I do want "any one" so your answer is perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need this?

```
var firstError = a.modelState["model.ConfirmPassword"];
```